# Use resource bundle strings in java backing code?

Tags: java, jsf

I'd like to retrieve a resource bundle string based on locale for a specific backing bean class.
In `*.jsf` files I'd just use `#{text['my.string']}`. How do I do this in my backing bean class?

ty

Comment: Using the class ... (drum roll) ResourceBundle? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleName").getString("my.string")`

Pay attention: bundleName is the name of properties file without the extension "properties". For example if you have file `messages.properties` you should call `ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages")`